# Get all photos loaded by their visibility?

Tags: javascript

I have original script: http://pastebin.com/ERWdaQym
I need to appear in the image, the image is displayed. Script worked when he was with html. But there was another problem, put this script in a separate file. But I did not get, get it to work so it worked.

I have an **library.js**, this file is automatically included in every page.:

```
var LIBRARY = {
   init: function() {
       $('image[itemprop = image]').each(LIBRARY.lazyLoad());
    },
    /**
     * LazyLoad images
     */
    lazyLoad: function(event) {
        $(function() {
            var $window = $(window),
                images = [],
                imagesToBeLoaded = 0,
                i,
                src;

            function throttle(func, wait) {
                var timeout;
                return function() {
                    var context = this, args = arguments;
                    if(!timeout) {
                        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            timeout = null;
                        }, wait);
                        func.apply(context, args);
                    }
                };
            }

            function inViewport($el) {
                var top = $window.scrollTop(),
                    left = $window.scrollLeft(),
                    bottom = top + $window.height(),
                    right = left + $window.width(),
                    offset = $el.offset(),
                    thisTop = offset.top,
                    thisLeft = offset.left,
                    thisBottom = thisTop + $el.outerHeight(),
                    thisRight = thisLeft + $el.outerWidth();

                return !(
                    bottom < thisTop ||
                        top > thisBottom ||
                        right < thisLeft ||
                        left > thisRight
                    );
            }

            // throttle so we don't do too many calls
            var lazyScroll = throttle(function() {
                // have all images been loaded?
                if(imagesToBeLoaded > 0) {
                    for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                        // data is there if nothing has been done to it
                        src = images[i].data('src');
                        // see if the image is in the view
                        if(src && inViewport(images[i])) {
                            // create a nice closure here
                            (function(img, src, i, $img) {
                                img.onload = function() {
                                    console.log('Loaded ' + i + ' ' + img.src);
                                    $img.attr('src', img.src);
                                    imagesToBeLoaded--;
                                };
                                img.onerror = function() {
                                    console.log('Could not load ' + i + ' ' + img.src);
                                    imagesToBeLoaded--;
                                };
                                // important to remove this to avoid duplicate calls
                                $img.removeData('src');
                                // start loading the image
                                img.src = src;
                            })(new Image(), src, i, images[i]);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // cleanup
                    images = void 0;
                    // why keep listening if there is nothing to listen
                    $window.off('resize scroll touchmove', lazyScroll);
                    // all images are loaded
                    console.log('Unloaded event listener');
                }
            }, 50);

            $('image[itemprop = image]').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    $img = $(this.innerText || $this.text()).filter('img');
                // make sure we got something
                if($img.length === 1) {
                    // remember the real image
                    $img.data('src', $img.attr('src'));
                    // use a blank image
                    $img.attr('src', 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7');
                    // cache a reference
                    images.push($img);
                    // replace noscript element with the image
                    $this.replaceWith($img);
                    imagesToBeLoaded++;
                }
            });
            // only add if we need it
            if(imagesToBeLoaded) {
                lazyScroll();
                $window.on('resize scroll touchmove', lazyScroll);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I need to connect the init: event that would run the script and images appear correctly, in other words, if a user comes to the image, then it is loaded. Tell me how to do it and what I need to fix?

Comment: I would suggest using this code - http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

Comment: Unveil not using, because I can't adding some attributes to img tag.

Comment: you don't need to add any attributes.

Comment: Can you show me the code for example?

Comment: There are code examples in the link I gave you. what's wrong with them?

Comment: I connected Unveyl.ys 
But I have very little information and pictures on the local server, loaded instantly. How do I know that unveyl working properly?

Comment: Code:
lazyLoad: function () {
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("img").unveil(200);
});...

Comment: well actually you do need to change the `src` of all the images to `data-src`. can you do that?

Comment: well, maybe you can put a script in the HEAD or something that changes all SRC to DATA-SRC but i'm not sure it'll work

Answer (score 0):

You can use document ready: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

something like:

```
$(document).ready(LIBRARY.init);
```

Comment: No! It's not right! I need run this script on each image in my site. This script connected to site. I don't know how I need correctly write this code, that should be work correctly.

Comment: Isn't that what your code `$('image[itemprop = image]').each(LIBRARY.lazyLoad());` is doing?

Comment: No. I need to run this script for each image on the site.

Comment: What do you think `$('image[itemprop = image]').each(...)` does?

Comment: I need to run a script to lazily loaded pictures

Comment: Your code *does* iterate over all pictures, see `$('image[itemprop = image]').each(function() {...}` halfway your code. The only thing you have to do is trigger the function `LIBRARY.lazyLoad` when the page is loaded, like `$(document).ready(LIBRARY.lazyLoad);`. As far as I can see, your function `LIBRARY.init` doesn't make sense.